# Prove that if G is bipartite, then there does not exists a subgraph g in G such that g is a cycle with odd number of edges?

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, proof-explanation, bipartite-graphs

I understand the intuition for this lemma but having a hard time proving it formally. I was thinking of using induction to show P(n)" graph with even edges" implies P(k+1)"an acyclic subgraph with odd edges". But what type of graph would you end up getting if you remove 1 edge from p(k+1), there are many types of even lengthed subgraphs,specifically that even lengthed subgraph is indeed a cycle or it is not? Thanks!

Comment: you seem to be trying to prove the iff form, but the question above is only one direction. here's a hint for the one direction part: try coloring an odd cycle with 2 colors. if you can't, prove it. then, prove that a graph takes at least as many colors to color as any subgraph of it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the sequence of vertices $v_0,v_1,\ldots, v_n$ represents a cycle (so $v_0 = v_n$).  Inductively show that $v_0$ and $v_{2k+1}$ are in different parts for every $k \geq 0,$ so $v_0 = v_n$ implies $n$ is even.

Comment: does that mean I have to do 2 seperate proofs, one showing P(n)" subgraph is odd length"" then P(K+1)" subgraph is even length and could be a cycle" AND P(k)" subgraph is even length" then P(k+1) "subgraph is odd length and is never a cycle"?

Comment: @neet I'm not sure where you're getting two separate proofs.  The sketch I've shown is the sketch of the whole, singular, proof of the statement you need to prove.  ---------- If a cycle in a bipartite graph must necessarily have an even number of edges, then it logically follows (since no integer is both even and odd) that no cycle in a bipartite graph can have an odd number of edges.